# How To Remove Parent Item From List

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to delete item from list when i press delete button. know it delete last record of the list. I have create a component with statefull widget for child.

1. ListView in parent file

   ```
           ListView.builder(itemCount: CartList.length,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             return MyCartItem(
               CartList[index],
               index,
               ((var data) {
                 if (data["status"] == "ProductRemoved") {                        
                   setState(() {
                     CartList.removeAt(index);
                   });
                 }
                 CalculateTotal();
                 UpdateCartCount();
               }),
             );
           },
         )
   ```
2. Child Component [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12XfwZVwJGtDfTQ27m2efFoY1oZ_Tm3ZE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

the child widget has to have an onPress property that is setted by the parent
and the parent passes the delete function to the child like so

```
void onItemDelete(index) {
  setState(() {
    CartList = CartList.items.where(i => i['id'] != itemId );
  })
}
```

```
ListView.builder(itemCount: CartList.length,
 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
   return MyCartItem(
     // add this parameter to the MyCartItem        
     onItemDelete, // <===============
     CartList[index],
     index,
     ((var data) {
       if (data["status"] == "ProductRemoved") {                        
         setState(() {
           CartList.removeAt(index);
         });
       }
       CalculateTotal();
       UpdateCartCount();
     }),
   );
 },
)
```

and in your **CartList** item call the method **onItemDelete** and pass the cart-item id